# how can show time as gmail format in PHP

Tags: php

[image: time format hint ---today print only time like 9:30 AM or 9:30 PM ;;Afetr yesterday print date like 7Oct or 6 Oct and after one year print 2/12/2015]

**shown in image time format hint ---today print only time like 9:30 AM or 9:30 PM ;;After yesterday print date like 7Oct or 6 Oct and after one year print 2/12/2015.how can do that in PHP.please help me**

Comment: I like [getDate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php). Make sure you adjust for those zeros.

Comment: you have to format your dates like this . http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

Here is the PHP script for exactly what you need..

```
function time_elapsed_string_in_helper($datetime, $full = false) {
  $now = new DateTime;
  $ago = new DateTime($datetime);
  $diff = $now->diff($ago);

  $diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
  $diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;

  $string = array(
      'y' => 'year',
      'm' => 'month',
      'w' => 'week',
      'd' => 'day',
      'h' => 'hour',
      'i' => 'min',
      's' => 'sec',
  );
  foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
      if ($diff->$k) {
          $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '');
      } else {
          unset($string[$k]);
      }
  }

  if (!$full) $string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);
  if (date('d', strtotime($datetime)) != date('d')) { 
    return date("d F", strtotime($datetime));
  }
  else if(date('Y', strtotime($datetime)) != date('Y'))
  {
    return date("m/d/Y", strtotime($datetime));
  }
  else 
  {
    return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just now';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin for this, strftime is not supposed to read current time.

The way to implement this is to get current time, compare if the printed value is older than two 12 hours or half a year and choose proper format.

Comment: can u explain in php coding take time zone india

Answer (score 0):

A little modify here

```
function time_elapsed_string_in_helper($datetime) {

if ((date('d', strtotime($datetime)) != date('d')) && (date('Y', strtotime($datetime)) == date('Y'))) { 
  return date("d/m", strtotime($datetime));
}
else if(date('Y', strtotime($datetime)) != date('Y'))
{
  return date("d/m/Y", strtotime($datetime));
}
else 
{
  return date("h:i a", strtotime($datetime));
}}
```